# UIWebView auto size in landscape (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiwebview

i'm new to the Swift programming language!

I'm building a simple app that shows a webpage, my problems is, when i rotate the device, the WebView isn't sized to fill the Scene...

I've tried to use this code:

```
func resizeWebView(){

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

}
```

i call this function on the viewDidLoad() function, is that right?

Are there anyway to do this? Everything that i found on the internet is for Objective-C...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a simple example:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

I did not use auto layout or deal with status bar issues, but no problem resizing on rotation.